# DocuSign Connect API brands could not be created

Tags: docusignapi

My website has been using DocuSign Connect API (SOAP) for years without issue.  Part of my website utilizes the brand creation functionality of the DS API (CreateAccountBrands).  This has worked flawlessly until very recently.

I now notice in the DocuSign Demo environment that the CreateAccountBrands calls return an InternalServerError with the message "Brands could not be created" but no other information is present in the trace log file.  All other DocuSign API calls still seem to be working fine.

Nothing with my payload has changed at all.  Has something recently changed with the payload requirements of the CreateAccountBrands call?

Comment: I would reach to customer support because there's not enough information to determine the issue. 
A few things to check: can you create brands via the UI? can you do this with the REST API? Can you try to create a new developer account (demo) and see if the issue persists? that can help isolate the problem

Answer (score 0):

I thought it could be that you reached the limits for brands but it seems to be 1900+

You can check Docusign's release notes to see if there are any relevant changes here: https://support.docusign.com/s/releasenotes?language=en_US&page=1

If you don't find anything then you can reach out to DocuSign's support by opening a ticket here: https://support.docusign.com/